# UIScrollView is not good with large images up to 5M for carousel view

Tags: ios, ipad

I have implemented carousel view with UIScrollView,
It works good with 40-50 images with 600*400 size, but it crashes with 150 images with 3-5Mb size.
How can I solve this problem, now I am working on iPad app.
thanks,

Comment: they are many 3rd party libraries  are there you can use them ,if you load all images into memory  you will get memory warnings just load images witch are visible or going to visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's very basic problem with UiScrollview,it's not recommended to use Scrollview with large number of images.
you can use instead UICollectionView with horizontal scrolling.
Of course you only need to show first row with paging enabled.

here are some hint for it.
First you need to custom flowlayout with horizontal direction.

```
@interface LayoutHorizontalThings : UICollectionViewFlowLayout
@end

@implementation LayoutHorizontalBooks

-(void)prepareLayout {
    [super prepareLayout];

    self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;

    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(110,130);
    self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

and then you have to set pageenabled to true.

```
yourCollectionView.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very surprising. You're better off using a default or custom UICollectionView. UICollectionView and UITableView have the benefit of flushing unused cells out of memory in order to preserve memory overhead. With UIScrollViews all of the memory overhead stays in place when you scroll the content offscreen.

UIScrollView is great when you have a page of content that is larger than the screen size but it isn't optimized for presenting an ordered collection of homogeneous items. This is when you should use UICollectionView / UITableView.

If you're stuck with the scroll view you can try to implement your own version of Apple's dequeue functionality by removing unused images once they are off screen and refreshing them once they reappear but then you're basically reimplementing a collection view.